# Configure pyCLI decorators to reraise exceptions correctly

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the pyCLI @cli.log.LoggingApp decorator to create a CLI app. While it correctly, if something in the code throws an exception, I only get "RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise" errors. If I remove the decorator, the exception gets reported properly.

Going through the docs, I *should* be able to add something like "reraise=(BaseException)" to the decorator to tell it to pass through all exceptions, but I cannot seem to get that to work.

Can someone provide me with a working example of using a pyCLI decorator that allows exceptions to pass through when one is not caught by the code?

The complete decorator I'm trying is:

```
@cli.log.LoggingApp(name="program_name", description="Program Short Description",
   date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', message_format='%(asctime)s | %(filename)s | %(message)s',
   reraise=(BaseException))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had time to dig into the code. This was happening because the pyCLI module was trying to re-raise the exception from a different scope. This is a bug in the module. I am submitting a patch to the author.